# How do I prepare SQL data for use with TransactionEncoder

Tags: python, sql

I've been attempting to import some transactional data into Python from a DB2 SQL table in order to use the mlxtend. I need to use TransactionEncoder to get it into the correct form, but I can't seem to find the correct format for the data to allow it to work.

All examples I find seem to use either a csv or a small amount of hand-coded rows to create a dataset, but this won't be viable with the data I will be using. I have a comma-separated list of each customer's items, but no matter how I format it once it is in Python, I seem to get a 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable' error during the TransactionEncoder. This is where I am currently;

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import getpass
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder


#Create dataset
 
odbc_dsn = 'ABCDEF'
db_user = input("Enter database username: ")

 # Create connection object
conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN = odbc_dsn,
    UID = db_user,
    PWD = getpass.getpass("Enter database password: "))

 # Run query and store output in variable 'd'
d = pd.read_sql_query(sql = "SELECT * FROM SUP.SJC_PYTHON_CROSSPURCH ORDER BY COMBO_COUNT DESC;",
                       con = conn)

 # Closes the connection
conn.close()
print(d)

df4 = d["COMBO_VARIABLE_AGG"].str.split(", ", n = -1, expand = True)
print (df4)

dataset = df4
#dataset2 = [['Milk', 'Eggs', 'Bread'],
#['Milk', 'Eggs'],
#['Milk', 'Bread'],
#['Eggs', 'Apple']]
#print(dataset2)

#Transpose and 1-Hot

te = TransactionEncoder()
te_array = te.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)
df = pd.DataFrame(te_array, columns=te.columns_)
print(df)

#FP_Growth
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import fpgrowth
frequent_itemsets_fp=fpgrowth(df, min_support=0.01, use_colnames=True)
#print(frequent_itemsets_fp)

#Association Rules
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules
rules_fp = association_rules(frequent_itemsets_fp, metric="confidence", min_threshold=0.8)
```

The section with Milk/Eggs/Bread was from the original example, which works with the stuff below. I'm guessing people must use SQL data in this way with Python, so was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction (in case you can't tell, I'm very new to Python).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has a similar issue, I think I managed to figure it out (after taking a bit of time to actually learn what the basics of Python are). It seems that I needed to turn the column of strings (which were lists of items separated by commas) into a list of lists. I first turned the string in each row into a list;

```
df4=d["COMBO_VARIABLE_AGG"].str.split(', ')
```

(this goes after the 'conn.close()')
I then turned the column of lists into one big list;

```
df4=(df4.tolist())
```

I'm not sure if that is the accepted way of doing it, but the rest of the code below now works.